# iptables problem new ip andresse

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a list access.txt

```
123.456.4.6

23.56.78.8

21.4.5.77
```

Run:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $i --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

my question is in the access.txt list, 
every minute coming a new ip andress.
And I need each time to do 
restart the iptables to get(add) the news ip andress.

How can I make to add the news ip address without restart?

Answer (score 2):

Use ipset for black- or whitelists, so the iptables rule is always the same:

```
ipset create whitewall hash:net
ipset add whitewall 123.156.4.6
ipset add whitewall 23.56.78.8
ipset add whitewall 21.4.5.77

iptables -A INPUT -i em2 -p tcp --dport 1234 -m set --match-set whitelist src -jACCEPT
```

Now you can `add` and `delete` addresses from ipset or `save` or `restore` on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

did not work
where is my mystake please i have 2 list create

ipset.whitelist.conf

iptables_rules_66

#

create whitelist hash:net family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536

add whitelist 22.21.78.21

add whitelist 22.22.44.5

#

## Set default chain policies

*nat

:PREROUTING ACCEPT

:INPUT ACCEPT

:OUTPUT ACCEPT

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT

COMMIT

*filter

:INPUT DROP

:FORWARD DROP

:OUTPUT ACCEPT

:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]

## Fail 2 Ban rules (let them be allways first)

-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh

## Allow established sessions to receive traffic

-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.66.0.0/10 -j ACCEPT

## -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1963 -m set --match-set whitelist src -j

ACCEPT

## -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT

## -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT

## from second server allow everything

-A INPUT -s xx.xx.xx.x -j ACCEPT

## Alow on vpn 80-1945-4546

-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

## -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 1945 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 7000 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 8096 -j ACCEPT

## Accept on localhost

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

COMMIT

#

/sbin/ipset restore < /etc/ipset.whitelist.conf

/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables_rules_66

did not work